# websocket connections not closing

Tags: websocket, connection

I want to make periodic attempts to open a websocket connection until it succeeds.  So I'm trying every 5 seconds and it seems to work initially, for about a minute or so.  i.e. with the server disabled, connection is attempted and then immediately closes with readyState set to 3, then 5 seconds later, another attempt, another same response.  But then after a minute or 2, it doesn't close the connection anymore, it just hangs in the connecting state (readyState==0).

```
function wsConnect()
  {
  console.log("trying to connect...");
  var socket = new WebSocket("wss://blahblah.com");
  socket.onopen=function(){console.log("open");};
  socket.onerror=function(){console.log("error");};
  socket.onclose=function(msg){console.log("close");};

  setTimeout(function(){console.log("RS:"+socket.readyState);socket.close();wsConnect();},5000);
  }
```

Interestingly, if I subsequently, fire up the server, it gets hit by dozens of connections presumably all the connections made that resulted in readyState 0 are queued up.  Is there any way to totally crush kill destroy a readystate 0 connection?  Can't close it cos it's not open.

Alternatively, how do I periodically make connection attempts that will allow me to connect when the server becomes available but without bombarding the server with large numbers of connections when all I want is one?

Browser: chrome

Once it starts responding with readystate 0, even a page refresh won't fix it.  Only going to a whole new domain and then going back does it seem to reset.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! What browser are you using?

Comment: Ya sorry should have said, browser is chrome.  Firefox also exhibits similar behavior.  I can't believe how much trouble this is giving me considering it's not a terribly unusual thing to do.  I just want the browser to keep trying until the server becomes available again.  Am I the only person having this problem?

Comment: Perhaps opening a bug report at http://crbug.com will help

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should not attempt another connection until the first one is closed and then perform the reconnect in the *onclose* event. This way you will not create another connection unless the first one fails.

```
function wsConnect()
{
    console.log("trying to connect...");
    var socket = new WebSocket("wss://blahblah.com");
    socket.onopen = function() { console.log("open"); };
    socket.onerror = function() { console.log("error"); };
    socket.onclose = function(msg) {
        console.log("close");
        setTimeout(wsConnect, 5000);
    };
}
```

Comment: Yup tried that very first thing but the problem is that after a minute or 2, the onclose dont get called no more cos it just seems to get stuck in connecting (readystate 0)